# Safari - WebkitAudioContext chokes on some mp3 files for unknown reason

Tags: safari, mp3, web-audio-api, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I'm having an issue with certain MP3 files in Safari only.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/ExjwWEp

In chrome, both buttons work to play both files. 
In safari only the first button works.

Why is this? Does safari just choke when it doesn't see  a ".mp3" suffix or is it something else?

- Both requests return "audio/mp3" Content-Type header.
- Both files can be downloaded as mp3s and played in any audio player
- Both files can be played directly through the safari address bar

But only one of the files plays programatically using WebkitAudioContext.

Failing code:

```
window.webkitAudioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MP3 file isn't valid.  There is multi-part form garbage at the beginning of the file.  If you open it with a hex editor, you'll see it:

[image: Hex Editor View]

Anywhere else that's playing this file is simply being nice to you.  :-)

Also, use `audio/mpeg` for your `Content-Type` header.  It doesn't matter in your case since you're using the audio context to decode the data... it doesn't know what the original `Content-Type` header was.  I'm mention it here for others, as it's a common mistake.

Comment: You sir are a savior, thanks. I was using AWS presigned url and sending ```FormData``` instead of the ```File``` object directly. Literally everything else plays it... Safari is so mean!